# fatal error: boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, clion

I am trying to run the `boost::python` tutorial in CLion on Ubuntu. I have installed boost and ran `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev`, however, the following still throws the library-not-found error:

`#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
 #include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>`

> main.cpp:2:32: fatal error: boost/filesystem.hpp: No such file or directory

I have added the `boost/` folder to my project directory, but the import is still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't need to copy anything to your project directory, when you apt get it should be in your systems include folder. I'm guessing `libboost-dev` doesnt come with `filesystem.hpp` - maybe try `apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev` - I'm not familiar with ubuntu so I'm not sure this is the issue

Comment: @ricco19 I deleted the folder and ran your command. I think this has to do with the way I compile the code. I am using CLion, I have changed the CMakeLists.txt file to find the boost package but I am getting `Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_system
          boost_filesystem`. Anything would help! Thanks!

Comment: Are there any other errors output when you tell CLion to reload the CMake project? I have run into problems myself when the installed version of Boost is newer than that supported by the version of CMake being used.

Comment: @SeanBurton it's worth mentioning that when I run `cmake .` instead of running the project from JetBrains, I don't get the error. But that is the only error I get.

Comment: By default CLion will use a bundled version of CMake, which may be older that the system version you have installed which will be used from the commandline. You could try changing the CLion options so it uses the system CMake to see if this helps.

Answer (score 12):

I have applied the proposal of @ricco19:

```
apt-get install libboost-filesystem-dev
```

This solved the problem for me.